# Cypress preventing API call from finishing

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I have a weird issue. I have a page that is sending an API (I'm using both `async/await` and `$.ajax().then` for testing).

On its own, it's working perfectly fine, with the code after the `await` and in the `then` firing. However, it doesn't work when running through Cypress. Although the network tab shows that the API has succeed, none of the code continue running, meaning that both of the `console.log` never gets called.

Originally, I was doing to intercepting to stub the API so I thought that's the issue, but now, removing that `.intercept` also do nothing. Where should I start looking?

Some related code:

```
//testing
describe('The feature', () => {
before(() => {
    cy.loginAsAdmin();
    // 01-Aug-2021
    cy.clock(1627740000000);
    cy.visit('/dataChecking');
});

beforeEach(() => {
    Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('PHPSESSID');
    cy.reload();
});

after(() => {
    cy.clearCookies();
});

describe.only('when no data is return', () => {
    it('will show no error box', () => {
        cy.intercept(
            'POST',
            '/dataChecking/forStore',
            // {
            //  body: {
            //      data: [],
            //  },
            //  delay: 5000,
            // },
        ).as('api');

        cy.get('#store-id').type('1');
        cy.get('#submitBtn').click();

        cy.wait('@api').then(() => {
            cy.get('#no-error-message').should('be.visible');
        });
    });
});
```

});

```
// Page code
$.ajax({
        url: '/dataChecking/forStore',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            storeId,
            from: from.toString(),
            to: to.toString(),
        },
    }).then((msg) => {
        console.log(msg);
    });

    const { data } = await $.ajax({
            url: '/dataChecking/forStore',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                storeId,
                from: from.toString(),
                to: to.toString(),
            },
        });
    console.log('hello');
```

API in network tab
[image]

Comment: You should create a catch block after `then` to see if there is an error throw from the $.ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Intercept need the url to match

```js
it('will show no error box', () => {

  cy.intercept('POST', '/dataChecking/forStore').as('api')

  cy.get('#store-id').type('1');
  cy.get('#submitBtn').click();

  cy.wait('@api').then(() => {
    cy.get('#no-error-message').should('be.visible');
  });
});
```

or you might need

```js
cy.intercept('POST', '**/dataChecking/forStore').as('api')
```

Comment: What's the different between your code and mine? Also, the problem is not with the intercepting, but with the behaviour of cypress when dealing with API

Comment: Yeah, I was looking cross-eyed - though you had missed the url.

Comment: But some things don't make sense - where is `async/await` in your code?  And ***none of the code continue running*** what does that mean? Please explain the error more precisely.

Comment: I only put in ajax since I think it's the same, have just added the async/await into it. I also explain what "not continue running" means. Please have a look :). Tks

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  I tried to reproduce, but works ok for me (used the stub because have no api set up). `cy.wait('@api')` succeeds, `console.log(msg)` shows `{data: Array(0)}`.

Comment: yeah it makes sense for it to work. I just don't quite understand what's happening and where to look for

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235916/discussion-between-tree-nguyen-and-electron).